# Backbone: How to fire the add event only once when add model arrays

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

Suppose I have an array of models:

```
var data = [model1, model2, model3, model4];
```

Then I want add these data to one collection an once:

```
myCollection(data)
```

and I also listen to the collection `add` event

```
this.listenTo(myCollection, "add", this.add);
```

But I found the `add` event fire 4 times, as the length of the models;

How can I let the `add` event fired only once, which means I only want to know when the whole models added entirely.

And I can't use `reset` event, cuz this action maybe happened multiple times and the data will be accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [trigger](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger) a custom event:

> `object.trigger(event, [*args])` 
>   Trigger callbacks for the given event, or space-delimited list of events. Subsequent arguments to trigger will be passed along to the event callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Underscore's debounce function.

Comment: Can you explain a little more with some piece of code?